# How to call a subpath endpoint in Go without call main path?

Tags: go

I'm having an issue with Golang using gorilla/mux.

I've declared an endpoint and certain subpath, but when I try to call the subpath BEFORE call it's main path, it returns me a 404 error.

So, there's my schema:

on main.go:
`services.StartRestService()`

on services package:

```
func StartRestService() {
    log.Println("Loading Rest Service")

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { mainHandleRequests(w, r, router) }).Methods("GET")
    http.Handle("/", router)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8083", router)) 
}
```

on another go file in the same services package:

```
func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}

func pong(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Pong!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: pong")
}

func mainHandleRequests(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, router *mux.Router) {
    homePage(w, r)
    router.HandleFunc("/ping", pong)
}
```

Running my application, if I try to call http://localhost:8083/ping it returns me 404 not found. Only if I call http://localhost:8083, and after that I call the ping endpoint, it works.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the router is unaware of the /ping endpoint until mainHandleRequests is called once.

So, the router should be set up and then not touched or changed in any way by incoming calls.

I have restructured your code a little:

```
func homePageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}

func pongHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Pong!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: pong")
}

func main() {
    log.Println("Loading Rest Service")

    router := mux.NewRouter()

    router.Path("/").Methods(http.MethodGet).HandlerFunc(homePageHandler)
    router.Path("/ping").Methods(http.MethodGet).HandlerFunc(pongHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8083", router))
}
```

Comment: So, I have to declare all my possible endpoints all in the same place? For example, if I need endpoints for "accounts", "animals" and "gadgets", and on each of them I have to declare other nested endpoint, I can't declare them in three different go files (for example accountsRestService, animalsRestService, and gadgetsRestService) ? I need to declare all the endpoints in the same file (just like the main in your example) ?

Comment: You can create your endpoints in different files. But you need to separate responding to calls and configuring the router.

Your mainHandleRequests function will be run on an incoming call AND configure the router. That is why you saw the endpoint appearing after a call was made.